# Как взять время не компьютера, а время по GMT?

Tags: javascript

Есть функция которая считает золото героя. Отсчет идет от времени последнего сбора золота и до текущего времени. Время берется из Date.now(), есть баг если время перемотать на компьютере то золото начинает прыгать в большую или меньшую сторону. Функция срабатывает каждую секунду и считает текущее золото. Считает все правильно, но баг с временем только

```js
function MathGold(hero) {
  const countGoldPerSecond = 1
  const currentGold = hero.resourse.saveGold; //условно 500
  const timeNow = Date.now()
  const lastTick = hero.resourse.goldLastTick //условно Date.now() - 10000
  const expectedTimeSec = parseInt((timeNow - lastTick) / 1000);



  const gold = currentGold + (Math.round((parseInt(expectedTimeSec) * countGoldPerSecond) * 100) / 100)

  return gold
}
```

Comment: Если время на компе изменили, то никакого другого у него нет. Запрашивайте время у какого нибудь сервера. А лучше все расчеты вести на сервере, если опасаетесь что недобросовестный пользователь вмешается в процесс

Comment: @Mike тогда у меня каждую секунду будет запрос к серверу, а это не ок

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now я бы посмотрел на ту функцию (и другие методы в performance). Кажется на неё не должно влиять изменение часов

Comment: @AlexeyTen функция показывает время прошедшее с момента загрузки страницы. А мне нужно время прошедшее с времени последнего  сбора **lastTick**

Comment: @IhorStoner можно один раз получить текущее время с сервера в начале работы, а дальше считать прошедшие секунды с помощью performance.now